# Creating a 6 variable Venn Diagram with Boolean values in 6 columns

Tags: python, boolean, venn-diagram, matplotlib-venn

I am a novice at python so I apologize if this is confusing. I am trying to create a 6 variable venn diagram. I was trying to use matplotlib-venn, however the problem I am having is creating the sets is turning out to be impossible for me. My data is thousands of rows long with a unique index and each column has boolean values for each category. It looks something like this:

|A|B|C|D|E|F|

|0|0|1|0|1|1|

|1|1|0|0|0|0|

|0|0|0|1|0|0|

Ideally I'd like to make a venn diagram which would show that these # of people overlap with category A and B and C. How would I go about doing this? If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful.

I found this person had a similiar problem with me and his solution at the end of that forum is what I'd like to end up at except with 6 variables: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-visualize-3-columns-with-boolean-values/36181/4

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might try to be more specific about your needs and what you have tried.

Making a six-set Venn diagram is not trivial at all, ever more so if you want to make the areas proportional. I made a program in C++ (`nVenn`) with a translation to R (`nVennR`) that can do that. I suppose it might be used from `python`, but I have never tried and I do not know if that is what you want. Also, interpreting six-set Venn diagrams is not easy, you may want to check `upSet` for a different kind of representation. In the meantime, I can point you to a web page I made that explains how `nVenn` works ([link](http://degradome.uniovi.es/vqf/SCD.html)).